# Endless compilation with TikZ. Bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling

If I try to compile this,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [rectangle, % <-- there's a syntax error
    \node [rectangle] (a) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

compilation never stops. Is this a bug in TikZ/PGF?

I use this version of latex:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2012/dev/Debian)
```

Comment: The input has an obvious syntax error.

Comment: I know. But shouldn't I get an error message?

Comment: Please, state your question more clearly, then.

Comment: you can even simplify your example to `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}\tikz\node [\node] (a) {};\end{document}` and it will show the same behavior. The reason seems to be the search for the path to apply the second node code however the second bracket completes the options declaration and the error-check cannot understand the nature of the problem while searching for the path.

Comment: @helami: Maybe you you could file a bug report/feature request at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=142562&atid=752792

Comment: Sorry, but discussions about error behavior and bugs of packages are not on-topic on it. You can't await proper behavior with invalid input.  Note that `,` is not a syntax error, but perfectly valid. Line breaks are ignored here, so you basically write `\node [rectangle, \node [rectangle] (a) {};`, i.e. the `rectangle, \node [rectangle` part is taken as options. Note that TeX doesn't match `[` with `]` as it does with `{` and `}`. Having `\node` there is invalid and making TeX produce an error message would be very difficult.